# why does my react switch router not work if my path has more then 1 forward slash in it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <section className='section'>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Articles} />
      <Route path= '/football' component={Articles} />
      <Route path= '/cooking' component={Articles} />
      <Route path= '/coding' component={Articles} />
      <Route path= '/article/:id' component={ArticleById} />
      <Route path= '/articles/comments' component={ArticleComments}/>
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </section>
</BrowserRouter>
```

so the route '/article/:id' and '/articles/comments' fails to load anything when i take thhe '/:id' or the '/comments' off the path the components load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your project is NOT using server side routing. I placed a  component in your parent Component (Articles) and clicked that link (which was set to go to article/1

e.g.

`<Link to="/article/1">CLICK HERE</Link>`

and it worked just fine. However, type in the URL bar

> http://localhost:9000/article/1

does not work...here's why...

If you don't have server side routing setup, then when you make a BROWSER based request (which is what you're doing via the URL bar) it will send off a request for the content at the location in the URL. The reason you're getting 404 NOT FOUND errors is because you're expecting webpack-dev-server to know that when you type /articles/1 it should serve a component, but as far as it can tell you've actually requested a folder called articles with a file called 1.

Because of this, you need a server to handle browser requests for locations.

You need a static router to match the request url to a path on your routes file which will in turn "return" that component to the browser.

Comment: I can help you out with the server side routing thing (or you can look into on your own if you wish) but nevertheless thats the problem. This should be the answer marked correct.

Comment: thanks josh i really appreciate the time you've already spent helping me i think i will be okay looking into it myself but if i get stuck i post my problem to you

Answer (score 0):

When you use a

`<Switch>` in React Router it will render the FIRST component that matches that path.

Is it rendering your NoMatch component when you have :id?

For /comments you should use a subroute e.g.

```
<Route path='/articles'>
    <Route path='/comments' component={ArticleComments} />
</Route>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply i thought it should be rendering the NoMatch component but its not, the NoMatch is only getting hit when i type the wrong path without a second forward /. I've just tried it with the sub-route aswell and im still getting the same result of a blank white screen with the below errors in the console

 GET http://localhost:9000/articles/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
9:9 
GET http://localhost:9000/articles/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED
9:13 
GET http://localhost:9000/articles/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you post a CodePen or more complete example of your code somewhere? Are you trying to use server side rendering? Are you using webpack? Your browser shouldn't be trying to find bundle.js at the URL you're requesting...this tells me your deployment is messed up and React Router isn't intercepting your URL request. Your browser router code should be the top level component in ReactDOM.Render()

e.g.

    `ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Switch><Routes>...</Routes></Switch></BrowserRouter>);`

Comment: here is links to the github 

https://github.com/chrisjones11/my-Northcoders-news/blob/master/src/index.js

https://github.com/chrisjones11/my-Northcoders-news/blob/master/src/components/App.js

yes im server side rendering using webpack. Im very new to react and this method of set up ive used is from a video tutorial i followed but it didnt go as far as showing the problem im facing now any pointers on learning the correct way would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is your code for server side rendering? You need to match the path on the server as well.

Comment: Give me a few. I am going to clone your project.

Comment: Okay. I found your problem.I will type it up as a reply

Answer (score 0):

As @Joshua Underwood says, the fact is **webpack-dev-server** try to fetch your script in nowhere. But I don't think it is the correct answer based on the fact that other route is work perfectly.  So, that is to say the problem is neither due to **webpack-dev-server** or **react** but your `index.html` itself.

I bet you have set `historyApiFallback: true` in `webpack.config.js`, and also you point your `bundle.js` something like `bundle.js` or `.\bundle.js`, which you should set it as `\bundle.js`. Otherwise, although the server handle the fallback correctly, but your `index.html` file have no idea which path it was found, and try to anchor your script based on the wrong path level.